# Render heterogenous collection with custom object name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, render

In my Rails app I have an `@events` collection of objects inherited from `Event::Base < AR::Base` model.

If rendering it like `render :partial => 'event', :collection => @events` it's possible to give an option `:as => :event` to change the name of a local variable corresponding to the object inside of the partial. But what to do when the name of the partial is not constant? The aforementioned way (`render @events, :as => :event`) doesn't work.

PS. There's a solution at [blog.obiefernandez.com](http://blog.obiefernandez.com/content/2012/01/rendering-collections-of-heterogeneous-objects-in-rails-32.html)  but it uses the last part of the partial name and this just doesn't fit for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself to verify, but this might work:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  def to_partial_path
    # assuming that you need different partials based on an attribute "variety"
    "events/#{variety}"
  end

end
```

You may also need to use the :partial key, eg: `render :partial => @events, :as => :event` instead of `render @events, :as => :event`

EDIT: This only works in Rails 3.2+ ... see [Obie's writeup on the topic](http://blog.obiefernandez.com/content/2012/01/rendering-collections-of-heterogeneous-objects-in-rails-32.html).

Comment: `render partial: @events, as: :event` did work! Thanks! It's so counter-intuitive to pass a collection as partial, I always thought it can only be a name of the file.